# Android app crashes when starting it: issue with toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to learn how to develop android apps by reading the book "Learn android Studio" by Adam Gerber and Clifton Craig. This question has been asked a lot and I've been trying to find a solution for 2 days now but I just can't fix it since I am fairly new to programming.

I am trying to build an app that allows for the creation of 1 line reminders. From what I understood, the book was written when the actionBar was still a thing in Android Studio so I am trying to figure out how to make my Toolbar appear with the new Android Studio version. I have the following in my RemindersActivity.

```java
package com.apress.gerber.reminders;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class RemindersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_reminders);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reminders_list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.reminders_row, R.id.row_text,
                new String[]{"first record", "second record", "third record"});
        mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)            findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I comment out the line setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and the remainder of my code the app runs fine but I can't see my action bar. However, when I leave everything the way it is the app crashes and doesn't run. Here is my Styles.xml file if that may help:

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

and my activity_reminders file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.apress.gerber.reminders.RemindersActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And finally here is my androidManifest.xml file. I am running api 23 with build tools 23.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.apress.gerber.reminders"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".RemindersActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you paste the crash log as well..

Comment: Remove your  app:popupTheme from toolbar.

Comment: You left out one of the most important pieces of info - logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your class file to attach toolbar to your activity

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_screen_ads); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setElevation(2);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

also make changes in your style

```
     <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Set it to true

Comment: Explain your answer. [From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10634472)